# Add % sign to a column using worksheet formatting

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I want to add "%" sign to the value in a column (I actually don't want to convert that to percentage, just want to add the sign).I tried the below code which converts values to percentage and then add (%) sign after the value. Is there any wayto just add the sign.

```
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%'})
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 40, format2)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to just add the sign.

Not exactly. You need to also convert the number to a percentage by dividing it by 100. Then it should work as expected. This is the default Excel behaviour, not just XlsxWriter's.

Here is an example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('percent.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%'})
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 40, format2)

worksheet.write(0, 3, .1)
worksheet.write(1, 3, .25)
worksheet.write(2, 3, .5)
worksheet.write(3, 3, .75)

workbook.close()
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In that case I think you can just do this:

```
Sub test()
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D100")

For Each c In myRange
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c.Row, c.Column) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c.Row, c.Column) & "%"
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I updated my answer.  If you need the row number to be dynamic then you can just add a long variable and set it to the last used row

Comment: It's not python it's VBA code.  You had excel as one of the tags and didn't state that you where only using python